# Read and handle input data when received

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on arduino project which involves it sending/receiving data from the iPhone to to an arduino through a BLE board. I am struggling with receiving data from the arduino back to the iPhone.

I have this function:

```
  func readPosition() -> NSString? {


        if self.positionCharacteristic == nil {
            return nil 
}
       self.peripheral?.readValue(for: self.positionCharacteristic!)
        if ((self.positionCharacteristic?.value) != nil) {
        return NSString(data: self.positionCharacteristic!.value!, encoding:
        String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) }

        return nil
        }
```

My problem with it is that I don't understand how to use it in a way that it will immediately read and use what was sent from the arduino. How would I code my project to accomplish this? I need to receive constant data from a sensor that is attached to the arduino

The receiving UUID if needed:

```
let PositionCharUUID = CBUUID(string: "A9CD2F86-8661-4EB1-B132-367A3434BC90")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely (but you need to check) that your characteristic supports `Notify` operations.  In this case you can use

```
self.peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: self.positionCharacteristic)
```

You will then get a call to your peripheral delegate's [`didUpdateValue:for:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) method